# LDAP assign user CRUD privs within a certain DN

Tags: ldap

I'm using ApacheDS and ApacheDS studio.  I've written a system that uses Spring-LDAP to manage users and groups.  The LDAP account used to read/write groups is admin.  The system needs to be deployed now and the sysadmins are guarding admin credentials.  I need to have them create a user that has just the read/write privs to CRUD objects within a certain DN only so I can provide that to my app as the manager account.  Preferably only certain kinds of objects can be updated by this account, but any object within a restricted DN would work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the ApacheDS documentation for [Prescriptive ACI](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/1.5/25-authorization.html)s